# CSS not getting updated through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am stuck in a silly problem. I have two divs (white coloured). Onclick them a class should be added which changes the color from white to blue. The class is getting added but the colour is not changing. (I do not need to addClass() just to change colour, but there will be more things in that class later, right now I have to execute it properly).

The divs has a class "thumbnail", onClick I want to add "border-glow".

```
// ImageBox component

// Author Sayantan Hore
// Created on 19.08.2014

// --------------------------------

function ImageBox(){
    this.outerContainer = null;
    this.imageBoxArray = [];
}
ImageBox.prototype.createOuterContainer = function(){
    this.outerContainer = $("<div></div>")
    this.outerContainer.addClass("outer-image-container");
    $("body").append(this.outerContainer);

}
ImageBox.prototype.createImageBox = function(){
    if (this.createOuterContainer === null){
        this.createOuterContainer();
    }
    var imageBox = $("<div></div>");
    imageBox.addClass("thumbnail");

    var closeButton = $("<div>x</div>");
    closeButton.addClass("btn-close");

    //imageBox.append(closeButton);
    this.imageBoxArray.push(imageBox);
    return imageBox;
}

ImageBox.prototype.loadImage = function(imPath, imageBox){
    var img = $("<img></img>")
    img.attr("src", imPath);
    imageBox.append(img);

    img.load(function(){
        //console.log($(this).height());
        imgWidth = $(this).width();
        $(this).parent().height(rowHeight);
        $(this).height(rowHeight);
        //console.log($(this).width());
        $(this).parent().width($(this).width());
    });
}

var rowHeight;
$(document).ready(function(){
    rowHeight = parseFloat(($(window).height() * 90 / 100) / 5);
    //console.log(rowHeight);
    var imageBoxObj = new ImageBox();
    imageBoxObj.createOuterContainer();
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        var imageBox = imageBoxObj.createImageBox();
        imageBoxObj.outerContainer.append(imageBox);
        var imPath = '../images/im' + (i + 1) + '.jpg';
        //imageBoxObj.loadImage(imPath, imageBox);

    }
    console.log(screen.availHeight);
    console.log($(window).height());
    console.log($(".outer-image-container").height());
    $(".thumbnail").on("click", function(){
        $(this).addClass("border-glow");
        alert($(this).hasClass("border-glow"));
    })
});
```

[**here is Fiddle:**](http://jsfiddle.net/sayantan_hore/1hkzrp8p/10/)

see line numbers 57-60 in javascript part.

Can anybody help please?

Comment: Always post your code in the question...

Comment: try `background-color: #0066CC !important;` http://jsfiddle.net/1hkzrp8p/11/

Comment: Always include the relevant code and markup __in__ the question, don't just link (not even to a fiddle). Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: Actually the code is big and a bit messed up, so I did not post it.

Answer (score 1):

```
.outer-image-container .thumbnail.border-glow{
    background-color: #0066CC; }
```

This should make the trick, just replace your borderglow class with this.

Answer (score 1):

the `background-color` in the class `thumbnail` is overriding the one in class `border-glow``because it gave more strong css selector. The simpler solution would be to edit the CSS like this :

```
.border-glow{
    background-color: #0066CC !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the following

```
.border-glow{
    background-color: #0066CC !important;
}
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1hkzrp8p/15/)**

Answer (score 0):

add  $(this).removeClass("thumbnail"); before

```
    $(this).addClass("border-glow");
```

Comment: Sorry, thumbnail has and will have a lot things that has to be there. So it cannot be removed. I needed to change colour, border-blow, opacity and some other things onclick. But it is solved now. Anyway thanks.